How to add legend list on BoxPlotChart (AmChart4)

I'm using a XYChart of AmChart4 to draw a BoxPlot chart

q1, q3, median, max, min

Sum Value is a LineSeries and displayed by the purple dot.



I want to add all the value on the X-Axis to the legend list and can toggle click to legend to display/hide the BoxPlot chart that match with clicked parameter. I can add but can not handle the event to display/hide



Tried
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend(); 
chart.legend.position = "top"; 
chart.legend.contentAlign = "right";
chart.legend.data = [{
                    name: "PARAM01_STEP_MEAN",
                },
                {
                    name: "PARAM01_STEP_MIN"
                },
...
            ]

Expected:

Add PARAM02_STEP_MEAN, PARAM02_STEP_MIN, PARAM01_STEP_MEAN, PARAM01_STEP_MIN to the legend list (include both Q1/Q3, MEAN, MAX, MIN & Sum Value

Can toggle click to them for display/hide the BoxPlot chart with clicked PARAM


